# Opencv redraw image when values are changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter

I have just started using OpenCV, I have been using harris corner detection function. I have written a script to look for black edges in a picture.

I have been struggling with implementing a slider to dynamically adjust the threshold of the image.

At the moment the slider only sets the value before the image is loaded. It does not get updated when changing the value by using the slider.

How would I go about getting the slider to continuously update the image when you move the slider?

Thanks in advance

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tkinter
import sys

slideVal =1
def showVal(value):
        global slideVal
        value = int(value)
        print (type(value))
        slideVal = value

def harrisCorn():
        time.sleep(3)
        print(slideVal)

        print ("the current slider value is: ",slideVal)
        img = cv2.imread('rawGun.jpg')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = np.float32(gray)
        #Changeing the value's in this function with : slideVal
        dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,slideVal,3,0.04)
        #result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
        dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

        # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
        img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

        imgSize = cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))

        cv2.imshow('dst', imgSize)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff:
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def slider():
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        s = tkinter.Scale(orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=225, command=showVal)
        s.pack()
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = slider).start()
    time.sleep(3)
    Thread(target = harrisCorn).start()
```

Comment: It looks like you have specified showVal as a callback for the slider update - if you just make that recall harisCorn() each time it's called, that would probably give you the behavior you are looking for. OpenCV does also have its own highGui slider that you can add to OpenCV windows without mucking with tkinter - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html

Comment: Definitely stick to either all OpenCV GUI or all TkInter GUI. Right now you end up with 2 message loops running in parallel. For someone without much experience with GUI code, that's just asking for trouble (multithreading adding further complexity). For example, in the current state of the code, calling `harrisCorn()` from the event handler `showVal` is definitely not the thing to do. A feasible fix would be adding a loop in `harrisCorn` and having `waitKey` wait only a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use `horrisCorn()` as the `command` function of the slider so that whenever the slider is changed, the image is updated.  Below changed code block is based on your code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tkinter

def harrisCorn(slideVal):
    slideVal = int(slideVal)
    print("the current slider value is: ", slideVal)
    img = cv2.imread('rawGun.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = np.float32(gray)
    #Changeing the value's in this function with : slideVal
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, slideVal, 3, 0.04)
    #result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
    dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)
    # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
    img[dst>0.01*dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]
    imgSize = cv2.resize(img, (1000, 1000))
    cv2.imshow('dst', imgSize)

def slider():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    tkinter.Scale(orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=225, command=harrisCorn).pack()
    harrisCorn(1)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    slider()
```

Comment: Managed to get the code working now thanks. As mentioned above in the comments I will probably rewrite this code to work with highGui to speed up the program, As of right now it's very slow